# Why is JQuery, autoNumeric reverting my textbox value to null?

Tags: c#, jquery

Sorry to ask a question about a plugin, but I'm having a really hard time figuring this out.

In a C# MVC application we're using the JQuery plugin, autoNumeric, to display currency format in a text box. The currency format displays correctly, but when I attempt to save the value to a database table, the value reverts to null: Null is saved to the table and nothing is displayed in the text box. When I remove the autoNumeric formatting the code works correctly.

Here is the autoNumeric code in the View:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('.auto').autoNumeric('init', { vMin: '-99999999999999.99', vMax: '99999999999999.99', aSign: "$ ", nBracket: '(,)' });
    });
```

And the code for the text box:

```
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.TableEdits[i].Amount, new { @class = "auto", style = "text-align:right;" })
            </td>
```

Hopefully this is enough information to work with, but if additional code is needed please let me know. I've consulted the documentation and it appears that I'm following the syntax correctly, but I must have missed something.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: You should check the request. Maybe something that's not numeric was sent to the server. The model bind proply fail to bind this value, turning this as null.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm looking into it. Thank you.

Comment: JS seems to work fine (http://jsfiddle.net/4nD8C/) so must be in the data sent.

Comment: Fals was correct. It was trying to send a string (including formatting) to the server. So had to remove the formatting and parse the string to a numeric value.